# Pandas: Count number of object in a particular column for each row

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies if the question is incomplete in some sense.

My dataframe has one particular column, which had multiple entries (objects) at each row. I want to count no of entries in this column for each row. Can anyone suggest way to do?
I have tried count(), len() but not getting the required output…

Example:

```
din=pd.DataFrame({'x':[['a','b','c'],['a','e','d', 'c']]})`

              x
0     [a, b, c]
1  [a, e, d, c]
```

Expected Output:

```
              x   count
0     [a, b, c]     3
1  [a, e, d, c]     4
```

Comment: Can you post a sample dataframe and expected output ?

Comment: try `value_counts`. for example `pd.value_counts(df['column']`

Comment: Are the multiple entries you mean in a list?

Comment: yes, multiple entries in a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.str` accessor and the method `.len()`:

```
din['count'] = din['x'].str.len()
```

Output:

```
              x  count
0     [a, b, c]      3
1  [a, e, d, c]      4
```

Answer (score 0):

If your columns are object type, anything you call is not vectorized (array math). If it's counting per row, you bust your cache for every lookup. There isn't an efficient way to do this unless you can normalize the columns up front and flatten your data in a matrix. Maybe try converting the column to a pandas Categorical.